# How to add Static Blocks to product descriptions in Magento?

Tags: magento

I would like to add static blocks to my products descriptions in Magento without using an extension.  I realize that there are extensions to enable this functionality such as Static Blocks Everywhere, but this extension is not compatible with my theme.  Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically do it in your theme, by adding this :

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Just to make sure, should I add this code to the view.phtml page under app\design\frontend\argento\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml ?

Comment: Yes, add this code in view.phtml where you want the block to appear.